# Subtract For Sequential Row ID's in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate between difference value of sequencel rows. For example, if exists rn and   one low rn (row number 4 and 5), that will be calculated.

Can you give me any idea about that?

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (assuming SQL 2005+) and [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;With Rows
As 
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) As RowNum 
    From Lag
)
Select R1.LagValue, R1.Value, R1.rn, R1.rn - IsNull(R2.rn, 0) As Difference
From Rows R1
Left Join Rows R2 On R1.RowNum = R2.RowNum + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx). It goes something like this:

```
select [value] - lag([value], 1, 0) 
    over (partition by [LagValue] order by [rn] desc)
from your_table
```